# Mono for Android shows no device

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, debugging, mono, visual-studio-2012

I have a registered version of Mono for Android.
If I try to debug on my phone (Galaxy S3) on my private PC, everything works fine.
But if I try it on my buddys PC, it doesn't work.
I don't know if I forgot something.

What I did:

- Install drivers (Kies)
- USB Debugging turned on
- Restart VS 2012

Hope, anyone can help me...

Comment: same problem here. Same device, different pc (both pc installed kies, vs 2012). One works, one doesn't. Have been searching but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off **Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)**

You can find this in your project's properties -> Mono Android Options.

Comment: Yes, i turned it off. But the project is not the problem.